# How to set and call ScrollLeft() position

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, position, window

I'd like to set the scrollLeft() position and call it back. Here's my codepen...

http://codepen.io/jareko999/pen/PNJgMq

When you click "Zoom out" you can scroll left to right. When you click on a box, it focuses on that box. Then, when you click "Zoom out", the scroll goes back to 0. However, I'd like the scroll to be where it was when you initially click on a box. Right now, if you click on say, the last box, then zoom out again, the scrollLeft position goes back to 0. I know I can set a variable...

```
var scrollPosition = $('body').scrollLeft();
```

But I'm not sure where to go from there. Even when I set this variable, the console says it can't read it. I'm novice in JS, but I'd really like to figure this out. If you have a better solution or a way to solve this with scrollLeft() or another method, please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `var scrollX = 0;` as a global variable in your JS file.

Then add `scrollX = document.body.scrollLeft;` at the top of your `$('.box').click(function() {` function.

Last, add `document.body.scrollLeft = scrollX;` at the end of your `function zoomOut() {` function.

Here is a working codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOzmyN

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. Give it best answer if it solved your problem so other people know it was fixed.

Comment: Just did. So when you set a variable to 0, does that mean it's setting the value as a number? So in the future, if I set a variable to 0, does that mean I want it to return a #?

Comment: That is good common practice. JS is a loose language so variable types can change and JS will try and guess what you are using. But usually if you want it to be a number, say `var x = 0;` and for strings say `var x = ""`

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the tip and the help.